# ListView with 2 objects adapter not working well

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Hello I trying to create listview with 2 objects call (`Customer, Problem`)

So the problem, when I run the app, is that I see the list view [like this](https://ibb.co/eu0t97) and for need example, I want to see this like this:

row 1.  Eran Peer

0544634631

Screen Protector Replace

row 2.  eran peer

0544634632

volume flex

and not like the photo.

the Customer Problem page code is:

```
  package com.example.eranp.clientpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CustomersProblemsPage extends Activity {

    ListView listViewCustomersProblems;
    List<Object> problemsCustomers;
    DatabaseReference databaseCustomers, databaseProblem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers_problems_page);
        listViewCustomersProblems = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LVCustomerProblem);
        databaseCustomers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customer");
        databaseProblem = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("problem");
        problemsCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = getIntent();




    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        databaseCustomers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //getting customer
                    Customer customer = postSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
                    //adding customer to the list
                    problemsCustomers.add(customer);
                }

                CustomerProblemAdapter customerProblemAdapter = new CustomerProblemAdapter(CustomersProblemsPage.this, (ArrayList<Object>) problemsCustomers);
                //attaching adapter to the listview
                listViewCustomersProblems.setAdapter(customerProblemAdapter);



            }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        databaseProblem.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                problemsCustomers.clear();
                    //iterating through all the nodes
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //getting customer
                    Problem problem = postSnapshot.getValue(Problem.class);
                    //adding customer to the list
                    problemsCustomers.add(problem);
                }

                CustomerProblemAdapter customerProblemAdapter = new CustomerProblemAdapter(CustomersProblemsPage.this, (ArrayList<Object>) problemsCustomers);
                //attaching adapter to the listview
                listViewCustomersProblems.setAdapter(customerProblemAdapter);

            }






            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

}
```

The Adapter code:

```
   package com.example.eranp.clientpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import static android.graphics.Color.BLUE;
import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;
import static android.graphics.Color.RED;
import static android.graphics.Color.blue;
import static com.example.eranp.clientpage.R.layout.customer_row;

/**
 * Created by Eran P on 16/04/2018.
 */

public class CustomerProblemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private Activity context;
    List<Object> objects ;



    public CustomerProblemAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Object> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.customer_problem_row, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = items;


    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        // Create holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_problem_row, null, true);
        TextView fName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textVFNameCp);
        TextView lName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textVLnameCp);
        TextView phone = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textVTeleleCp);
        TextView proDeviceShort = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.pro_device_det_shortCp);
        Object a = (Object) getItem(position);


            if (a instanceof Problem) {
                proDeviceShort.setText(((Problem) a).getProDevDetShort());
                if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 1)
                    listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(RED);
                if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 2) {
                    listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
                }
                if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 3)
                    listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
            }
            if (a instanceof Customer) {

                    fName.setText(((Customer) a).getfName());
                    lName.setText(((Customer) a).getlName());
                    phone.setText(((Customer) a).getPhoneNum());

            }






        return listViewItem;

    }
}
```

The Xml ListView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.eranp.clientpage.CustomersProblemsPage">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LVCustomerProblem">





    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the XML Problem Customer row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.eranp.clientpage.CustomerAdapter">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/fName"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/textVFNameCp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVLnameCp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lName"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/telephone"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textVTeleleCp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/pro_device_det_shortCp"
        android:gravity="center"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

thank you for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create an adapter for type Object. Your problem is this piece of code:

```
if (a instanceof Problem) {
    proDeviceShort.setText(((Problem) a).getProDevDetShort());
    if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 1)
        listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(RED);
    if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 2) {
        listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
    }
    if (((Problem) a).getUrgency() == 3)
        listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
}
if (a instanceof Customer) {

    fName.setText(((Customer) a).getfName());
    lName.setText(((Customer) a).getlName());
    phone.setText(((Customer) a).getPhoneNum());

}
```

You try to display the Customer details and the Problem details in the same view, but an Object can either be a Customer or a Product. It cannot be both, hence your view will either display the Customer details or the Problem details.

In my opinion, you should create a new class called CustomerProblem that captures all the information you need about each Customer and their Problems. And then you can create a new Adapter for CustomerProblem.

I would also recommend you research the ViewHolder pattern.